# How do i write these jquery methods in pseudo-code?

Tags: jquery, pseudocode

I am struggling to understand how I can write these in terms of pseudo-code.

```
  function makeHeader(label, width){
      //make the header element
      newHeader = $("<th/> <br/>")
        .html(label)
        .addClass("col-sm-"+width)
      return newHeader
  }
```

I am referring to the .html and .addClass parts, I don't really understand how I can write that in terms of pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write this:

```
function makeHeader(label, width){
    newHeader = $("<th/> <br/>").html(label).addClass("col-sm-"+width)
    return newHeader
}
```

Into pseudocode, you can just look at each statement and see what it's doing, and if you need help, look at the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com). But here's the full pseudocode:

```
Define a function makeHeader, which takes parameters label and width
    Define a variable newHeader, which is HTML markup <th></th><br/>.
        Set the innerHTML property of the element contained in newHeader to the label parameter passed to the function
        Add a class to the element contained in newHeader. The class added will be col-sm- followed by the width parameter passed to the function
    Return the newHeader variable from the function
```